# understanding recursion in java without the use of iteration (loops etc)

Tags: java

Good Evening,
I am trying at the moment to understand Recursion through this simple example

```
public class exM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(myMethod(0)); // change the power to 1,2,3,4
    }

    public static String myMethod(int n){
        if (n==0){
            return "*";
        }
        else {
            return myMethod(n-1) + myMethod(n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now its obvious that if 0 is used, it goes directly to * which is printed out.
Next, 1 is used. I can understand that is goes to else and back to our method with 0 and prints out "*" + "*" which we get "**".

What I can't understand is why when we change the power to 2, it brings back 4 asterists instead of 2.

Can someone explain to me how this occurs?

Thank you in advance

Comment: there are some really nice answers here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write out the recursion, it will be more obvious for you to understand.

```
myMethod(0) = *

myMethod(1) = myMethod(0) + myMethod(0) = * + * = **
```

so for myMethod(2):

```
myMethod(2) = myMethod(1) + myMethod(1) = myMethod(0) + myMethod(0) + myMethod(0) + myMethod(0) = ****
```

Comment: i really liked the tree example above , but using this example i could understand what was going on. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

because you call the function with n-1 which in the case of 2 is 1, for each call. You call the function twice, so you have two recursions going on with the value 1 each. Since 1 != 0 the 2 recursions spilt up in 2 recursions each again, this time with value 0 and since this is your stopping condition it will print theses 4 asterisks.

So basically

```
                             myMethod(2)
                        /                  \
               myMethod(1)                  myMethod(1)
               /         \                 /         \
     myMethod(0)       myMethod(0)  myMethod(0)      myMethod(0)
         *                 *            *                *
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through it.

1. You input 2.
2. `2 != 0` so it goes to the `else`
3. Now it will return `myMethod(1) + myMethod(1)`
4. Now if you step into each of the `myMethod(1)`, those return `**`
5. `**` + `**` = `****`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to analyze when n = 0, n = 1, n = 2 with a pencil and paper.

With this recursion you will realize the tree that the program is creating.

If `n = 0` you have one '*'.

If `n = 1` you call twice the method with n = 0 --> 2x '*' --> '**'

If `n = 2` you call twice the method with n = 1 --> 2x (2x '*') --> '****'.

If you want that the number of '*' were the value of `n` the code is:

```
public static String myMethod(int n){
    if (n==0){
        return "*";
    }
    else {
        return myMethod(n-1) + '*'; //One '*' more for each call.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this function you will get the following row if you increase n by 1 starting from 0: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ...
This is because every time n != 0, you do the function 2x for every time n is larger then 0

Answer (score -1):

I thought it is straightforward.

When you pass in 2, it will return

```
 myMethod(1) + myMethod(1)
```

which translates to ** + **...